# How to disable Enforce HTTPS for facebook auth at localhost?

Tags: django, facebook-authentication, social-authentication

I tried to configure social authentication via Facebook in my Django project.

As I am testing at localhost (already included the http-based site in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`) , I need to disable **Enforce HTTPS**.

My fb app is now in development mode, but by default **Enforce HTTPS** is enabled and couldn't be changed apparently. How can I fix it?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Use ngrock to test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot disable it anymore, it is required for [security reasons](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security#https)

> Enforce HTTPS. This setting requires HTTPS for OAuth Redirects, and it
>   requires and Facebook JavaScript SDK calls that return or require an
>   access token are only from HTTPS pages. All new apps created as of
>   March 2018 have this setting on by default, and you should plan to
>   migrate any existing apps to use only HTTPS URLs by October 6, 2018.
>   Most major cloud application hosts provide free and automatic
>   configuration of TLS certificates for your applications. If you
>   self-host your app or your hosting service doesn't offer HTTPS by
>   default, you can obtain a free certificate for your domain(s) from
>   Let's Encrypt.